# How to use terminal with createdb and URI?

Tags: postgresql, database-connection, uri

The [URI connection-string](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/libpq-connect.html#id-1.7.3.8.3.6) can be so complex, here an standard example:

```
  createdb "postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/sandbox"
```

of course, it not works with *createdb* ("template1: FATAL"), that is the question. The URI is working fine with `psql`, eg.

```
  psql "postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/postgres"
```

**I am looking for anything with the expected behaviour**, no matter if the name of the command is other than `createdb`.

---

PS1: on my env. there are password, etc. even for `postgres` user, and all my scrips are using *URI connection-string* standard, no more `-U` etc. options. The focus in this question is URI standard.  Using modern client and connections, v9+.

PS2: as its tradition and philosophy, we expect [orthogonal behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_instruction_set) in the commands offered by PostgreSQL. `psql` and `pg_dump` are orthogonal about URI; `psql`, `pg_dump` and `createdb` are orthogonal about `-U`  option...  I was expected some orthogonality about URI use... 
Or there is an **architecture bug**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-createdb.html
createdb does not claim to accept URI as dbname, while psql does:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html

what should happen when you

```
 createdb "postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/sandbox"
```

it should read first argument as is and create database with such name (which happens for me btw):

```
MacBook-Air:~ vao$ psql t -c "\l pos*"
Timing is on.
Pager usage is off.
                                               List of databases
                         Name                          | Owner | Encoding | Collate | Ctype | Access privileges
-------------------------------------------------------+-------+----------+---------+-------+-------------------
 postgres                                              | vao   | UTF8     | C       | UTF-8 |
 postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/sandbox | vao   | UTF8     | C       | UTF-8 |
```

this behaviour match manual:

> dbname
>
> Specifies the name of the database to be created.

The NAME of the db TO BE CREATED, while psql dbname can be uri of db to connect to...

Comment: Hi VaoTsun, thanks all explanations, but I am looking for a "hidden solution", because is expected that all commands will work with URI, not only `psql`... So, if there are no similar command (similar to `createdb`) where we can supply an URI, there are a **architectural bug** in PostgreSQL. As its tradition and philosophy, we expect [orthogonal behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_instruction_set) in the commands offered by PostgreSQL. Sorry for being so vague, I edited the question to enhance the point.

Comment: Adrian's comment about createdb, etc. is important, *"While not officially **deprecated** they are not high on the list of programs anyone cares about"*... So, in this context your answer also make sense, shows a bug that will never be fixed. **The user-community can fix it: by abandoning** that commands, using only `psql -c` direct commands. PS: you was the first, so I chose your good answer. My comments are only for philosophical discussion.

Answer (score 9):

clusterdb, createdb, createuser, dropdb, dropuser, reindexdb and vacuumdb are utility commands that are wrappers around SQL commands. While not officially deprecated they are not high on the list of programs anyone cares about. Most folks these days use some sort of scripting to do what they do. If you want to use a client program and a URI to do CREATE DATABASE then:

```
psql "postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/postgres" -c 'CREATE DATABASE my_test_db'
Null display is "NULL".
CREATE DATABASE
```

Or pass in a file using:

```
psql "postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/postgres" -f db_create.sql
```

UPDATE 12/05/2020

Seems there was an undocumented feature that has now been revealed. For most of these commands(not *user) there is a `--maintenance-db` option.  From [CREATEDB](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/app-createdb.html) dev documents:

> --maintenance-db=dbname

> Specifies the name of the database to connect to when creating the new database. If not specified, the postgres database will be used; if that does not exist (or if it is the name of the new database being created), template1 will be used. This can be a connection string. If so, connection string parameters will override any conflicting command line options.

Where the connection string can be a `URI`.

Comment: Thanks Adrain, to show the vision of **"deprecated  commands"**... In this context your answer  shows that is a bug, and that bug will never be fixed... But  we, **the user-community can fix it: by abandoning** that commands.

Comment: A bug is promised feature that does not work. For these programs the ability to use a URI is not promised, that feature just do not exist. The programs are already being abandoned.  They exist primarily for backwards compatibility to support work flows created before there where other options.

Comment: Yes, I agree, we are talking about "specification error" (not implementation error). As in any [software development life cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_development_process), when PostgreSQL grows and evolves, the old [module or command specifications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_specification) must evolve too... Currently (2020!) there is a specification-inconsistency between evolved `psql` (v12 ecosystem) and these archaic commands.  The **URI must be promised in each command specification**. PS: your answer is correct, here only philosophical discussion.

Comment: @PeterKrauss. It seems they where an undocumented but somewhat broken feature. In latest dev docs [createdb](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/app-vacuumdb.html) under `--maintenance-db=dbname`. See [Postgres Weekly](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/160429764790.31096.4134207403833989706%40wrigleys.postgresql.org)  under 'Tom Lane pushed:'  There are several commits related to connection strings.

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting `PGHOST`, `PGHOSTADDR`, `PGPORT`, `PGDATABASE`, `PGUSER` and `PGPASSWORD` environment variables as described in [Environment Variables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html) documentation section.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Daniele, **make sense (!)** and works, but the question is *"How to use ... URI?"*, and, in the context of the question the setting variables is excluded, is the alternative that I not want.